# Why can't I return Object in Java linked list traversal when using recursion?

Tags: java, oop, object, recursion, linked-list

In the book, Cracking the Coding Interview (6th Edition), a problem asks me to:

> Implement an algorithm to find the the kth to last element of a singly linked list

And later, the author claims:

> Unfortunately, we can't pass back a node and a counter using normal return statements.

She is referring to the Java language in the above statement. She later on shows that we can only print the kth to last element in singly linked list in Java.

My question is this: Why can't we pass back a node when the recursion is popping frames? Why can't we add another argument to the recursive function such that that argument is set at the right time (i.e. when index = kth item) to the node we are looking for? I have been thinking about this since last night, and I just can't wrap my head around it.

The example answer provided looks like this:

```
int printKthToLast (LinkedListNode head, int k) {

    if(head == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    int index = printKthToLast(head.next, k) + 1;
    if (index == k) {
        System.out.println(k + "th to last node is " + head.data);
    }
    return index;
}
```

Comment: Because you cannot change the return type that way. It's `int` and you cannot simply decide to return a `LinkedListNode` out of the sudden. If you call a method that returns a `LinkedListNode` in the `if` you cannot return that one, because your method only returns `int` values.

Comment: My point was that we can leave the return type as int. However, when we have found the correct type, we then place the reference to it into a third parameter that we add to the function above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right when you say that we can "add another argument to the recursive function such that the argument is set at the right time". For example, this function works in the same way as the solution you posted:

```
private void printKthToLast(LinkedListNode head, int k, int index) {

    if(head == null) {
        return;
    }

    if(index >= k) {

        System.out.println(head.data);
    }

    printKthToLast(head.next, k, ++index);
}
```

My guess is that the author was trying to illustrate that recursion typically "**divides a problem into sub-problems**, solves these sub-problems, and **combines the results**" (that is, the classic *divide-and-conquer* method). In this case, the *division of problems into sub-problems* is carried out when we call the recursive function on the "next" element, because we are getting closer to the base case (head == null). The *results to combine* is the index, which must be recursively incremented to determine when a node must be printed. This is why the index establishes the return type of the function (int). This is the correct way to solve the problem recursively. What you suggest is a possibility, but passing "index" as a parameter is neither *division of problems into sub-problems* nor *combining the results*.

In addition, it is also important to consider that, in Java, methods are not only identified by their names, but also by their input parameters, return types, etc. So, these two methods ...

```
private int printKthToLast(LinkedListNode head, int k)

private void printKthToLast(LinkedListNode head, int k, int index)
```

... are entirely distinct, even though they have the same name (this is called polymorphism). Therefore, including these two methods in the same solution would not be recursion.

Answer (score 0):

`LinkedListNode` is used internally by the `LinkedList`.

There are no **public methods** on a `LinkedList` that allow to retrieve the internal `LinkedListNode` (actually called `Entry`).

Therefore, given a `LinkedList`, you cannot get access to the internal node.

Yet, if it is just to go through the list, you can simply use an iterator and recurse over it:

```
int printKthToLast (Iterator<E> it, int i) {
    if(!it.hasNext()) {
       return 0;
    }
    E e = it.next();
    // ...
}
```